# Restlet routing with query string

Tags: java, restlet

I have a resource that currently is routed like this:

```
router.attach("/{version}/content/{language}", ContentResource.class);
```

I want to add to this resource a query string that will look something like this:

```
router.attach("/{version}/content/{language}?segment={segment}", ContentResource.class);
```

The thing is, that when I try to get to the resource with the routing, I fail to get into it.

Can someone explain why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to specify query parameters at the route definition level. If you want to use a query parameter named `segment`, here is the way to do:

- Route definition

  ```
  router.attach("/{version}/content/{language}", ContentResource.class);
  ```
- Get query parameter value

  ```
  public class ContentResource extends ServerResource {
      String value = getQueryValue("segment");
      (...)
  }
  ```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 1):

You should define the route behavior:

```
TemplateRoute myRoute = router.attach("/{version}/content/{language}?segment={segment}", ContentResource.class);
myRoute.setMatchingQuery(true);
```